# Number guesser program throwing exceptions Java

Tags: java, exception, methods

I am trying to add exceptions to a program i've already wrote. I need to write exceptions when the user tries to cheat on a number guess program for the higher and lower methods as well as add a try/catch on the game to display the error. I almost have it written correctly but and exception is thrown right before the last possible outcome. Attached is the class file i wrote along with the program to run the game.

Here is my class for the number guesser logic

```
public class NumberGuesser {
    private int min, max, midpoint, origMin, origMax;

    public NumberGuesser()
    {
        min = 1;
        max = 100;
    }
    public NumberGuesser(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        min = lowerBound;
        max = upperBound;
        origMin = lowerBound;
        origMax = upperBound;
    }

    public void setMin(int value)
    {
        min = value;
    }

    public void setMax(int value)
    {
        max = value;
    }

    public int getMin()
    {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax()
    {
        return max;
    }
    public void higher()
    {
        min = getCurrentGuess() + 1;
        if (min == max)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No more possible outcomes");
        }
    }

    public void lower()
    {
        max = getCurrentGuess() -1;
        if (max == min)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No more possible       outcomes");
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentGuess()
    {
        midpoint = (max + min) /2;
        return midpoint;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        min = origMin;
        max = origMax;
    }
}
```

Here is the program that runs the game.

```
import java.util.*;
public class GuessingProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do
        {
            playOneGame();
        }
        while (shouldPlayAgain());
    }

    public static void playOneGame()
    {

        char input = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        NumberGuesser game = new NumberGuesser(1,100);

        System.out.println("NUMBER GUESSER GAME");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Think of a number between 1 and 100");

        while (input != 'c')
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.print("Is your number " + game.getCurrentGuess() + "?" +
                        " (h/l/c): ");
                input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                if (input == 'h' || input == 'H')
                    game.higher();
                else if (input == 'l' || input == 'L')
                    game.lower();
                else if (input == 'c' || input == 'C')
                    game.reset();
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, You are cheating!!!");
            }

        }
    }
    public static boolean shouldPlayAgain()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Here is my output and the number its supposed to guess is 77

### NUMBER GUESSER GAME

> Think of a number between 1 and 100
>   Is your number 50? (h/l/c): h
>   Is your number 75? (h/l/c): h
>   Is your number 88? (h/l/c): l
>   Is your number 81? (h/l/c): l
>   Is your number 78? (h/l/c): l
>   Is your number 76? (h/l/c): h
>   Invalid input, You are cheating!!!
>   Is your number 77? (h/l/c):

Comment: Which line throws which exceptions?  What do you see in your debugger when you step through the code?

Comment: which line has the error ?

Comment: how about max - 1 == min

Comment: so i don't get any errors thrown until i get near the end of the output that is displayed above. In the output I choose higher from 76 because my number is 77. It throws an exception first and then tells me is your number 77. My homework assignment states that i need to throw and illegalStateException when there are no more possible outcomes and then a try/catch exception in the programming running the game to show the that a user response of h or l is not attainable

Comment: `min` will be 76+1=77 after that, and `max` is 78-1=77. That's why it throws the exception.

Comment: i understand that. I just trying to figure out how to fix my higher and lower methods to allow it to guess the right answer but then throw and exception if I try to cheat because no more outcomes are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `min` and `max` reach the same value, that means you've found the correct value. I think you want to throw `illegalStateException` if you say the number is higher/lower after you found the correct value, it is, `max < min`.